# Input File name doesn't gets updated on removing files from uploader neither I can add the same file

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently working on React. The on-Click event on `<Input type="file" />`opens the explorer where I can select and upload files, the image file name is displayed next to the upload button, to the S3, I have a remove button next to the upload button, on-Click action on remove button displays the confirmation modal to remove the upload files, but the file name next to the input menu isn't updated and I can't upload the same file which I had uploaded.

Upload Function

```
const uploadFile = (e: any) => {
        if (e.target.files[0]) {
            const formData = new FormData();
            ///
            PostImgFile(formData); // POST Methods to S3
        }
    }
```

For Confirm Modal Action

```
    const deleteFile = () => { 
           hideConfirmModal('confirmDeletion')
       if(imageDetails?.imgId){
            DeleteImgFile(). //Delete Method
       }}
```

```
<input type="file" id="imgFile" style={{ display: 'none' }} onChange={uploadFile} />
<input type="button" onClick={() => confirmModal('confirmDelete')}. hidden={fileName?.length < 1} />
```

Comment: Please add all the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to set the value back to null, i.e by using `useRef` we have to set the property of the input value null. I wish I had more input but I hope the solution below works.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

  function App() {
  const hiddenFileInput = useRef(null);
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

  function removeFile() {
    hiddenFileInput.current.value = null;
    setImage(null);
  }
  const onChange = (e) => {
    const fileUploaded = e.target.files[0];
    if (!fileUploaded) return;
    setImage(fileUploaded);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Home</h1>
      <input type="file" ref={hiddenFileInput} onChange={onChange} />
      <button onClick={removeFile}>Remove Image</button>
      {image && (
        <img
          src={URL.createObjectURL(image)}
          alt={image.name}
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

[Link to Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-upload-file-yzybc1?file=/demo.js)